# Is it possible to search jdom for attributes?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

Is it possible in jdom to get the children of a node that share a certain attribute without having to look at all children in bruteforce?
Is search in logarithmic time possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is search in logarithmic time
>   possible?

No, because that would require some sort of index keyed on that particular attribute, and why would JDOM keep such an index?

You could have an [XPath](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/xpath/XPath.html) implementation that builds such an index internally to speed up repeated searches, but it would still have to build it first.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to create an index on the specific attribute, you could use SAX and create an  index *as* you parse the document.  This could give you O(1) to find the attribute, after you constructed the index.

In JDOM, a logrithmic search would be impossible because, in divide and conquer searches an ordering of the nodes is assumed (like in a binary search tree).  Since the `Element`s of a JDOM `Document` have no ordering, there is no way to shrink the search space.